# Counting number of lines in a file using grep and wc

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to display a number of lines in a file using grep and word count (wc -l) with a pipe.

I tried many different methods but neither of them wordked. The file is in /home/[User]/[Folder]/[File Name.Extension].

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: How don't they work? `wc -l` should be all you need.

Comment: What did you try exactly? Show us.

Comment: I have to use both grep and wc -l. it works when i only use wc -l but I am required to use grep and wc -l with a pipe. I tried to do that but I couldn't get it working

Comment: I tried grep /home/[User]/[Folder]/[File Name.Extension]/ | wc -l

This did not work

Comment: What are you expecting `grep filename | wc -l` to do?

Comment: I am expecting it to display the count of the number of lines

Answer (score 12):

You don't need `grep` to count the number of lines, `wc` is sufficient :

```
wc -l filename
```

should work.

`grep` is useful only if you wan't to filter the file content, say you want to count the number of lines that contain the word `life`, then :

```
grep "life" filename | wc -l
```

will give you the results.